# Erro Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, if, entrada-de-dados, substring

Estou tendo problema ao fazer com que o meu programa retorne o IF de uma maneira correta, quando coloco o FOR ele conta o número de vezes que esta na variável, se eu digito uma entrada menor que 14 ele ao invés de cair no if da essa mensagem de erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
 For input string: "11111111111111" 
  at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) 
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652) 
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770) 
  at application.Principal.main(Principal.java:17)
```

Da mesma forma se eu digito um número muito maior que 14 ele retorna a mensagem que quero que está no IF.

Segue código:

```
package application;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

        
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.println("Digite seu cnpj: ");
            String cnpj = sc.nextLine();
            int n = cnpj.length();
            String cnpjFormatado = cnpj.substring(0, 2) + "." +
                                   cnpj.substring(3, 5) + "." +
                                   cnpj.substring(6, 8) + "/" +
                                   cnpj.substring(9, 12)+ "-"+
                                   cnpj.substring(13, 14);
            
        
            
            
            for(int i = 0; i < cnpj.length(); i++ )
            
        if (n !=14) {
                System.out.println("cnpj invalido, digite um formatado valido");
                return;
            }
            else{
            //System.out.println(cnpj.replace(" ", "") + "\nO tamnho da string é: " +cnpj.length());
            System.out.println("O CNPJ sem formatação é: " +cnpj);
            System.out.println("O CNPJ formatado é: " +cnpjFormatado);
            }
        
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala, Otávio. Seu código só precisa de alguns ajustes.

Nesse caso o ideal é que você valide o cnpj antes de formatá-lo. Você também não precisa do for.

Abaixo, eu coloco uma solução pra você. Veja se atende sua necessidade.

Obs.: Apenas comentei o trecho que você não precisará mais e reposicionei o if.

```
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite seu cnpj: ");
    String cnpj = sc.nextLine();
    int n = cnpj.length();

    // validando cnpj antes de formata-lo
    if (n != 14) {
        System.out.println("cnpj invalido, digite um formatado valido");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String cnpjFormatado = cnpj.substring(0, 2) + "." + cnpj.substring(3, 5) + "." + cnpj.substring(6, 8) + "/"
            + cnpj.substring(9, 12) + "-" + cnpj.substring(13, 14);

    /*
     * for (int i = 0; i < cnpj.length(); i++)
     * 
     * if (n != 14) {
     * System.out.println("cnpj invalido, digite um formatado valido"); return; }
     * else {
     * 
     * } não precisa do for :)
     * 
     */

    System.out.println("O CNPJ sem formatação é: " + cnpj);
    System.out.println("O CNPJ formatado é: " + cnpjFormatado);
```